# How to detect if a directive element is *not* clicked in Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I am trying to implement the "deselect" function for several directives like buttons and popovers. That is, I want my functions to trigger when the user clicks on an element that is *not* a part of my directive template. Currently, I'm using the following JQuery code:

```
$('body').click(function(evt){
  if($(evt.target).closest($('#directive1')).length == 0 ){
    //deselects first directive
  }

  if($(evt.target).closest($('#directive2')).length == 0 ){
    //deselects second directive
  }

})
```

Is there a better way to do this in angular?

Answer (score 3):

#### A simple directive that detects click outside an element (without jQuery):

http://jsbin.com/wimeyoruxo/2/edit

```
app.directive('onDeselect', [ '$document', function($document) {

  return {
    scope: { onDeselect: '&' },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      var clickHandler = function(e) {

        // Check if the target is our element or it's descendants
        var target = e.target;
        while (target) {
          if (element[0] === target) return;
          target = target.parentElement;
        }

        // trigger the function
        scope.$apply(function() {
          scope.onDeselect({$event:e});
        });
      };

      $document.on('click', clickHandler);

      // clean handler on destroy
      scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        $document.off('click', clickHandler);
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Use it like so:

```
<div on-deselect="doSomething($event)"></div>
```

Comment: I ran into a problem with this implementation. target.parentElement cannot be used to traverse elements inside a directive template. It shows that their parent is 'null'. so the onDeselect function will trigger even when you *select* the current directive element